# Realtime minifying coffeescript in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I serve a javascript file which is customized at the moment it is requested. I do this through a controller. I created a template views/controller_name/custom.js.coffee

First I stumbled across the issue the coffee script was not compiled in production, but this was solved by moving the two gems coffee-rails and uglifier outside the assets group.

```
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem 'yui-compressor'
end
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
```

Now this part works, but the script is not processed by uglifier. My question, how do I minify the javascript which is served this way?

Thanks

Comment: How much customization are you doing? Why not make the bulk of your script static assets and inject a few vars your script can refer to for its dynamic response at runtime.

Comment: Why you not just put all you code into assets/javascripts folder? Then make rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 0):

Write an after_filter:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js
  after_filter :uglify, :only => :custom

  def custom
    @ivar = 'Custom'
  end

  def uglify
    response.body = Uglifier.new.compile(response.body)
  end
end
```

I actually tried this out (as I've never had to generate JavaScript dynamically, and I've never written an after_filter), and it worked. This seems like a perfect case for an after_filter: your response body is JavaScript, and you want to modify your response (by uglifying it) before sending it to the client.

Comment: Does not work for me. The after filter runs, Uglifier returns an uglified script, but I still get the original script in the browser and redis cache.

Comment: Or when I reorder the cache_page/after_filter calls, but then the uglify step is not cached!

Comment: Using an around_filter (installed after caches_action) and `self.response_body = Uglifier.new.compile(response.body)` I could make it work (=uglified code lands in the cache, uglify is not called for a cached response).